# Pasar id en funcion con javascript in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Tengo un pequeño problema al pasar las id a través de una función, tengo el siguiente código js que si lo coloco en la pagina .cshtml al final como script funciona sin problema alguno y realiza la validación correspondiente.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var birthdate = new Date($("#FecNacVal").val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
            var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
            var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
            var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
            $('#EdadVal').val(age);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pero ahora que lo coloque en la carpeta de los js en ASP.NET Core MVC y lo coloco como función con parámetros me arroja errores, si alguien me podría dar la mano para saber que estoy realizando de manera incorrecta.

```
function ValidarFecha(idFec, idEdad) {
var ver = $('#' + idFec).val();
console.log(ver);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#"+ idFec).on("change", function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var birthdate = new Date($('#'+ idFec).val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
            var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
            var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
            var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
            $('#' + idEdad).val(age);
        });
    });
}
```

Al ejecutar la función en el modo desarrollador me arroja el sgte error.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLInputElement]

Aqui coloco el codigo del llamado a traves del input.

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
    <input id="FecNacVal" asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" type="date" placeholder="FECHA NAC." class="form-control" onchange="ValidarFecha(FecNacVal,EdadVal)" max=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Agradezco de su ayuda, indicando que estoy realizando de manera errónea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puede mostrar el código donde llama esa función `ValidarFecha(idFec, idEdad)`, me parece que ahí está el problema

Comment: Actualice la pregunta para colocar el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya entiendo cambia esto

```
 onchange="ValidarFecha('FecNacVal','EdadVal')"
```

ya que en el la función js estás esperando los id de los elementos,

en js tiene que cambiar esto

```
function ValidarFecha(idFec, idEdad) {
    var ver = $('#' + idFec).val();
    console.log(ver);
    var now = new Date();
    var birthdate = new Date($('#'+ idFec).val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
    var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
    var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
    var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
    $('#' + idEdad).val(age);
}
```

Si se fija como en el html está asignando la función directo en el `onchange` ya dentro de su js no necesita volver a asignarlo por eso funciona a la segunda, xq la primara vez lo que hace es asignar el evento

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ahora tengo otro problema, al realizar la selección de la fecha en primera instancia no me visualiza el resultado , vuelvo a escoger la fecha y ahí si, a que se debe o que podría estar erróneo? me puedes ayudar?

Comment: Seguro, mira tienes que hacer varios cambios, voy a agrgarlo en la misma respuesta para no crear otra

Comment: Muchas gracias, sos un héroe sin capa, un abrazo campeón!

Comment: jajaja Por nada, me alegro que haya resuelto el problema